# asp.net how to test load balancing is working

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

Our infrastructure team has configured a a load balancing using Radware. Basically we have 3 web server that are load balanced.

Before we go live I would like to test and make sure that load balancing is working. How do I test the following:

> 1. 3 servers are load balanced and requested are evenly distributed. (Any automated tool exists?)
> 2. Asp.net InProc session are working.

Comment: You may have better luck on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

You can test by first generating an artificial load on your site (with any one of a number of load generators). Then have a look at the Windows Performance Counters for each site: things like HTTP requests per second and CPU use would be reasonable high-level metrics.

Yes, there are automated tools, but they usually require quite a bit of setup, and the better ones charge a fee. Perf counters are fast, easy and free.

As @swannee said, InProc sessions won't work in a load-balanced scenario unless your load balancer is configured to use sticky sessions. It's better to use SQL Server sessions with load balancing.

FWIW, you can test your software in a "mini" load balanced scenario on a single server by enabling IIS web gardens (multiple worker processes), from the AppPool config dialog.

Comment: Totally right on the Perf Counters.  Very easy to set up and use in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in the IIS server logs to see how many hits each server is getting?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953324.aspx

Also, unless you are using sticky sessions, you are going to have problems with InProc session.  It won't work on a server farm (unless as stated you have sticky sessions turned on).  If you don't have sticky sessions, you'll be able to tell real quickly that your session is being lost between requests with just some manual testing.

Answer (score 0):

Our organization makes a series of ping and advanced status pages. These pages are monitored by our load balancers so it can take out unhealthy nodes in the event one node loses a connection to a database server or the node itself is having issues.

Our ping pages spit out the server name that you're connecting to and the status. They are avaliable by the common server names themself, like server01.application.com/ping and server02.application.com/ping but more important, they all answer on application.com/ping.

Refreshing the page will show us a new connection (you can see the server name change).

To test load you could use WCat, it's not the easiest tool to setup and script but it works.

To test sessions. you'll need to build out some pages that you can do load testing on to test sessions